# listAll() does not work for firebase in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

i have created  a function to list all files with in a reference.mStorageRef is defined public.

```
 public void ListFiles()
    {
        Log.d("FETCHING_DATA_STATUS","STARTED");
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("ImageFolder");

      
        mStorageRef.listAll()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                        for (StorageReference prefix : listResult.getPrefixes()) {
                          
                            Log.d("Storage_Prefix :",prefix.getName());
                        }

                       /* for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
                           

                        }*/
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                 
                        Log.d("FETCHING_DATA_STATUS","Failed due to"+e.getMessage());
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ListResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ListResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("FETCHING_DATA_STATUS", "FINISHED");
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

but when i execute this i get following ouput:

```
D/FETCHING_DATA_STATUS: STARTED
W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
D/FETCHING_DATA_STATUS: FINISHED
W/example.larn: Checksum mismatch for dex base.apk!classes2.dex
    Could not merge the profile. Clearing the profile data.
```

how can i use list all  correctly.Please help

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `for (StorageReference prefix : listResult.getPrefixes()) {` and run in the debugger, does it reach that breakpoint? If so, what happens if you step through the code from there?

Comment: Is this line `Log.d("FETCHING_DATA_STATUS","Failed due to"+e.getMessage());` printing something in the logcat?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes this breakpoint is reached but control does not go inside for loop.may be because listResult is empty

Comment: @AlexMamo no this line does not print anything in Log cat

Comment: It seems that `ImageFolder` contains no prefixes in that case. My guess is that you're looking for files, but your code is listing subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping over `listResult.getPrefixes()`, which are the **subfolders** in your `ImageFolder`.

Since you indicate you want to list **files**, you should loop over `listResult.getItems()` instead.

I find keeping the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/ListResult()) open key to quickly fixing this sort of common mistake.

Comment: can u also tell me how to store downloaded Uri to storage of phone.

Comment: That's a different question, but this should be a good strting point: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files